# problem running a python discord bot in vps

Tags: python, discord.py

I try to run my bot xerion.py and I get an error. Basically, in my computer everything works fine, the modules are executed etc. The problem is in the VPS, the Cogs are not loaded.

Does it take a library or something?

`root@webservice:~/xerion# python3 xerion.py xerion.py:18: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited client.load_extension(f"modules.{folder}.cog") RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback 2022-10-23 22:08:43 INFO discord.client logging in using static token 2022-10-23 22:08:44 INFO discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 1f2c3649fd651b7354223a1d4f25b39e). Xerion has started correctly`

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says you didn't await an async function:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited 
client.load_extension(f"modules.{folder}.cog")
```

Cogs & extensions were made asynchronous in `discord.py v2.0`. The [migration guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous) explains how to... migrate... to 2.0.

Comment: Sure, but the thing is, it WORKS on my computer. On the VPS it doesn't

Comment: And what version of `dpy` do you have on your computer vs on that VPS? I'm willing to bet that it isn't the same version. **This code doesn't work in 2.X**. If it _doesn't_ raise this error on your computer then you're not on 2.X. If it _does_ raise this error on your VPS then your VPS **is** on 2.X.

Comment: DIscord in vps it's 2.0.1

Comment: @Law that's what I said in my comment. You don't have 2.X on your own PC so you're not getting it locally.